# Persist pinecone long-term memory between Auto-GPT restarts

Tags: artificial-intelligence, vector-database, autogpt

Every time I stop and restart the Auto-GPT even with the same role-agent, the pinecone vector database is being erased. How can I persist the memory so I can keep all the data that have been gathered and start from where I left it?